# Etale homotopy type of simplicial preheaves

Tags: homotopy-theory, etale-cohomology

Etale topological type of a simplicial presheaf $X$ on the etale site of a scheme 
is a pro-space. A simplicial presheaf can be written as a coequalizer of  presheaves $P_n$, and each such presheaf is a colimit of representables $X_i$. Then $Et(X)$ is defined as a coequilizer of $Et(P_n)=\text{colim} Et(X_i)$ where $Et(X_i)$ is Friedlander's definition of etale topological type. This definition is due to Dan Isaksen. Given this definition is there a version of the comparison theorem for schemes over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I believe so, see recent work of David Carchedi.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I guess if one can replace the two colimits with hocolims then comparison theorem in this case should be a direct consequence of the classical one.